# Получить последний элемент массива (не меняя массив)

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции

Получить последний элемент массива (не меняя массив). Использовать функцию.
У меня есть такой код для получения, он правильный? И как правильней его в функцию поместить?

```js
let index = [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8];
for (let i = 0; i<index.length; i++);
console.log(index.pop())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция returnLastItem будет возвращать последний элемент переданного в нее массива:

```
let myArray = [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8];
let myArray2 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 15];

function returnLastItem(arr) {
  return arr[arr.length - 1];
}
console.log(returnLastItem(myArray));
console.log(returnLastItem(myArray2));
```

> 8
>
> 15

Если в функции всегда будет один и тот же массив, то это будет выглядеть так:

```
function returnLastItem() {
  let myArray = [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8];
  return myArray[myArray.length - 1];
}
console.log(returnLastItem());
```

Второй способ является не очень хорошим решением, так как лишает Вас гибкости при использовании функции, - в первом примере Вы можете получить последний элемент любого массива, во втором только тот, что определен внутри.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 4):

Не очень понятно, что Вы пытаетесь сделать. Вы делаете перебор, но при этом используете метод `pop`, который удаляет последний элемент массива и возвращает его значение, при этом перебор просто стоит для "галочки". По вопросу можно проще, достаточно узнать количество элементов в массиве (метод `length`) и использовать это значение в качестве ключа.

```js
let index = [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8];
console.log(index[index.length - 1]);
```

Comment: А как его в функцию поместить?

Comment: @Matc в следующем ответе показали как

Answer (score 0):

да кроме как 
ar = [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8];
ar[ar.length - 1] чтоб не портить массив других методов нет

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer" zoompage-fontsize="14)

Comment: старайтесь давать более развёрнутые ответы

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4];
let last = arr.slice(-1)[0];  
console.log(last);
 //or
console.log( [1,2,3,4].slice(-1)[0]  );

//см. функцию js slice
```

Comment: slice подобна функциям Linq  в C# take, skip. Или строковой функции substring. Короче в написании, чем 
 СуперДлинноеИмяМассива[ СуперДлинноеИмяМассива.length-1] и нагляднее.

Comment: Комментарии служат только для уточнений. Для [правок есть кнопка под сообщением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1090152/edit)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let index = [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8];

console.log(index.at(-1)); // 8
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]